# Serialize a pthreads Stackable object

Tags: php, object, serialization, pthreads

How can I `serialize()` a Stackable (from pthreads) object? When I my own class extends `Stackable` and serialize the object it would print something like this:

`C:5:"Test1":16:{140417464034096' . "\0" . '}`

Comment: json_decode() maybe help you...

Comment: Decode? Or rather encode?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't mess with serialization !!!**

You are looking at the physical address in memory of the object you serialized, the serialization API is hi-jacked by pthreads, don't mess with it.

If you are requiring the object in some kind of serial form then make use of the JsonSerializable interface or create your own interface.